# How can I define the number of occurrence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

In the PHP, fourth argument limits the number of occurrence to that number:

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

For example:

```
$string = 'this is a test';
$pattern = '/s/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, 'S', $string, 1);
//=> thiS is a test

/* If I remove that 1 which is the last argument in preg_replace, the output will be:
*  "thiS iS a teSt"
*/
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: That's default behavior in JS. If you want to exchange all you'll have to add the *global* flag - `/s/g`

Comment: @ClasG Yes I'm familiar with `g` flag in JS, But I want to know how can I limit exchange the specific number? for example just 3 first occurrence.

Comment: In JS, you can use a regex without the `g` flag to replace something once: `"this is a test".replace(/s/, "S")`. If you use the `g` flag, it replaces all occurrences. I’m not aware of any easy way to replace up to _n_ times.

Comment: To my knowledge JS doesn't support that. Maybe someone else knows.

Comment: Without a simple `for`-loop I might add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a counter outside the replace method (*like I did in the below function*):

```js
function replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, $limit) {
    var counter = 0;
    return $subject.replace($pattern, function(match) {
        return ++counter > $limit ? match : $replacement;
    });
}

var $string = 'this is a test';
var $pattern = /s/g;

O.innerHTML = replace($pattern, 'S', $string, 1) + '\n'
              + replace($pattern, 'S', $string, 2);
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Just one question, what is `x` in this line `return ++counter > limit ? x : 'S';` ? You have not defined it, So it is contains what?

Comment: `x` is taken as arg (the macthed text)

Comment: @stack. I changed it to `match`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var string = "this is test"
   ,pattern = /s/g
   ,replacement = "S"
   ,maxReplacements = 2
   ,i = 0

console.log(string.replace(pattern, match=> i++ >= maxReplacements ? match : replacement))
```

It just count replacements, and if it's more than 2, stops replacing.

See demo on [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/vuwema/1/edit?js,console).